# How to change icon in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have the following code:

```
$('.wpFolders.co_files').bind('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
            getFileById(data.args[0].hash.replace('#', ''));
        }).jstree({
            'plugins' : ['html_data','themes','ui','types'],
            'ui' : {
                'select_limit' : 1
            },
            'core' : {
                'animation' : 0
            },
            'types': {
                'default' : {
                    'icon' : {
                        'image' : '/admin/views/images/file.png'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I have a basic unordered list I would like to have displayed as a list of files. I'm trying to use the "types" to change the icon but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I checked their docs [link](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) and even when using almost identical code nothing seems to happen.

From my understanding of the code above the default type of my tree should have the icon I specified but nothing happens, all I get is the default folder icon.

Any ideas? Sorry if the question seems basic but I find the documentation hard to follow when trying to do basic things. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two problems:

1. I needed to add the "type" in my rel attribute of my list objects (I created a default and file type).
2. I forgot one level in my array declaring the types, the code had to be like the following:

   ```
   $('.wpFolders.co_files').bind('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
       getFileById(data.args[0].hash.replace('#', ''));
   }).jstree({
       'plugins' : ['html_data','themes','ui','types'],
       'ui' : {
           'select_limit' : 1
       },
       'core' : {
           'animation' : 0
       },
       'types': {
           'types' : {
               'file' : {
                   'icon' : {
                       'image' : '/admin/views/images/file.png'
                   }
               },
               'default' : {
                   'icon' : {
                       'image' : '/admin/views/images/file.png'
                   },
                   'valid_children' : 'default'
               }
           }

       }
   });
   ```

I don't really understand why my code is breaking in the WYSIWYG, sorry if it's ugly. Anyway, I hope this can help someone.

Comment: What are the js files you had to import for ui & types plugin ? was the basic jstree.js file enough ?

Answer (score 25):

After an headache...
I found a solution.

```
    <li data-jstree='{"icon":"path/file.png"}'></li>
```

I suggest to **don't** modify the css code.

PS The "types" plug-in is not necessary.

Comment: I can verify that this is a correct and working solution. So if you will put  a little png to your root `images` folder then you should use path like  `<li data-jstree='{"icon":"../images/services.png"}'>`

Comment: If someone need to add font awesome icon you can just write `<li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-check"}'>`

Answer (score 24):

I was able to replace several icons using the following CSS, without using the Types plugin. Hopefully this helps someone else as well!

```
    /* replace folder icons with another image, remove leaf image */        
    li.jstree-open > a .jstree-icon {background:url("imageOpen.gif") 0px 0px no-repeat !important;}
    li.jstree-closed > a .jstree-icon {background:url("imageClosed.gif") 0px 0px no-repeat !important;}
    li.jstree-leaf > a .jstree-icon { display: none; }


    /* replace checkbox icons */
    li.jstree-unchecked > a .jstree-checkbox, li.jstree-undetermined > a .jstree-checkbox 
    {
        background:url("uncheckedImage.png") 0px 0px no-repeat !important;
        width: 32px;
        height: 29px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
    li.jstree-checked > a .jstree-checkbox
    {
        background:url("checkedImage.png") 0px 0px no-repeat !important;
        width: 32px;
        height: 29px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though this would work it would also change the icons for all trees on my page. In my situation I had a tree that had nothing but folders and one with nothing but files so I wouldn't this change to be global.

Comment: Any way to use stacked font-awesome icons in jstree as HTML or classnames (not as image)? Have you ever tried?

Answer (score 17):

You may change the icon with the new API, without HTML, CSS, or plugins.

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).set_icon(nodeId, "/images/blabla.png");
```

Comment: Well, this is the best solution for those using new jstree vesion.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: nodeId is the nodes ID..  (or jstree node reference object) for instance you can do: `var nodeId = $(#tree).jstree(true).get_node("node_name");`

Answer (score 10):

To hide the folder icon use the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .jstree li > a > .jstree-icon {  display:none !important; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

jstree includes its own file icon (in addition to the default folder icon), add `'icon': 'jstree-file'` property to node to show it

Answer (score 3):

The way to change icon based on the level:

```
jQuery('#tree-edit').on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {

      //do something
    }).on("open_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
        jQuery.each(data.instance._model.data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key + ", " + val);
           if (key.length < 4 || key=='#') {
               jQuery.jstree.reference("#tree-edit").set_type(val, "selectable");
           }
        });
    }).on("loaded_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
        console.log(data);

    }).jstree({
        'plugins': ["search", "types"],
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': 'http://www.google.com/json',
                'data': function(node) {
                    return {'id': node.id};
                }
            }
        },
        'types': {
            'selectable': {
                'icon': 'http://elpidio.tools4software.com/images/icon-ok-small.png'
            },
            'default': {
                'icon': 'http://www.fabulatech.com/printer-for-remote-desktop-server-help/img/icons/warning-small.gif'
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying so many configurations unsuccessfully, I found a great idea!

By using online photo editor https://pixlr.com/editor/ I have opened icon image file under the path:

```
jstree\themes\default\32px.png
```

And I opened the folder icon I want to replace

[image]

Replace it easily and save :)
I think it is the best after 2 hour struggle.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
lst_item = [];
$('#city_tree li').each(function(){ lst_item.push($(this).attr('id')); });
$('#city_tree').jstree(true).set_icon(lst_item, "/static/global/plugins/jstree/province.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script works for me:

```
$('div#jstree').on('ready.jstree click', function (e, data) {
        $('i.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-themeicon jstree-icon').addClass('fa fa-lg fa-user');
    });
```